# Ionic/Capacitor - GeoLocation WatchPosition timeout

Tags: ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

There are two question I wanna ask.

1. The value  for `timeout` option is in `seconds` or `miliseconds`?
2. Where to execute code if the `timeout` reached? (do something after timeout)

.

```
let wait: string;
wait = Plugins.Geolocation.watchPosition({
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    timeout:5 // i dont if this is seconds or miliseconds
}, (position, err) => {
    // do something

    Plugins.Geolocation.clearWatch({
            id: wait
    });
});

// i want to detect if the location still doesnt detect, and it already time-out, i want to do something
```

The documention is too simple.
Very hard to understand. https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/geolocation/

Answer (score 1):

The timeout is defined in **miliseconds** based on the assumption, that the Capacitor API is probably equal to the [Web Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions). If the timeout is reached and watchPosition() couldn't get a position, you should be able to check your *err* value.